# Few questions about german patterns often seen in computers or mobile phones

Tags: translation

First of all, I'm an software developer. Our company has a plan about adding german language support to our application. Most of the things can be translated really quick by using Google Translate but it can do mistakes sometimes.

1. For a loading screen, is it better to use Laden 84% or Wird geladen %84?
2. What do germans usually use for their softwares when there's a button that says 'Try Again' when an internet connection is failed or anything that needs a 'Try Again' button. Google Translate says 'versuchen Sie es noch einmals' but a I searched Google a little bit and most of the time, Safari, Chrome and other browsers used 'Nochmal versuchen'. Which one is better and correct?
3. Connection failed should be 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen' right?

I'm a newbie in German language. I want to learn this language even if it's last thing to do in my life. Thank you for your upcomming support!

Comment: Not native speaker, but many experience with German IT. 1) I would use "wird geladen" 2) "nochmal Versuchen" is better, on UX reason: it is short 3) correct.

Comment: I recommend software developers to contact professional translators and pay them for such jobs. This at least will give you immaculate results. - The www.proz.com website is a good place to search for qualified freelancers.

Comment: I'm a software developer, and user of both English and German language software and I strongly advise to hire a professional **technical** translator who does software translations for a living. If you don't, you end up with funny terms no German can make sense of. I remember *Kanalreiter* for *channel tab*. It came up in a configuration dialog and only translating it back to English made me know what was meant.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "This at least will give you immaculate results" - I'm a software developer and my impression is that reality is very, *very* far (in a negative way) from that claim. At least from what I've seen, professional translators, even technical ones, as Janka suggests, translate the text to provide a solid volume of translated text in the application (i.e. so the use of a fallback to the default language isn't visible in virtually each dialog box), but it must be followed by hours, if not days of work by developers and product management to clean up and fix the nonsense ...

Comment: ... delivered by the translators that doesn't make any sense in context (or sometimes even without). Not to mention that "more elaborate technical details" are almost invariably lost on those translators, e.g. placeholders (that the software would substitute with actual values) getting translated along with the rest of the text is an issue that crops up regularly and apparently cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the *loading* part, both versions are common, but the % is most times behind the number. Alternativly you could use "84% geladen". Also common is only the percentage without any words, as it's most times pretty obvious it stands for *loading*.
"Nochmal versuchen" or even better "erneut versuchen" is most commonly used in the *try again* part.
"Verbindung fehlgeschlagen" is correct, you rarely something else in this case.

Comment: Laden 84% is common? It sounds wrong. I would definitely recommend "84% geladen" or "Wird geladen: 84%".

Comment: I actually see it quite often. I like "84% geladen" more, too, but on my perception it is indeed common. Often like "Laden... 84%" with reappearing dots.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.